# Behaviour of action bar with fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

Is it possible for a fragment to have its own action bar ? I have seen that we can change activity's action bar from fragment but can we have a brand new action bar for a fragment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use Toolbar. Every fragment can have it's own Toolbar, however when you load the fragment you must set the Toolbar to act as Activity ActionBar like so:

```
((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: tysm. Can you also tell me if i can provide theme that can entire theme of toolbar including color of status bar ?

Comment: Can you also tell me if i can provide theme that can change entire theme of toolbar including color of status bar ?

Comment: Status bar color can be only changed on Android 5 and newer. You can theme the toolbar like so: `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />`